# Cannot integrate Firebase iOS SDK - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I've been trying to get this `SDK` installed into my iOS project without much success.

At first, I tried to install it manually, using the setup instructions from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app

However, after following the `readme` file exactly, when I try use this code:

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

After importing `Firebase.h` into the header file, it doesn't recognise the `FIRApp` and the reason seems to me missing files from the framework as `FIRApp.h` doesn't exist in the headers.

So, I resorted to the much-hated, `Cocoapods` installation. Everything installs fine and no warnings show during the `pod install` part. However, again, when I add the following code: `[FIRApp configure];` I am present with a different error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

For the life of me, I cannot figure this out. I have searched Google and SO with various solutions that haven't helped.

I would like to get it working with Cocoapods as I have done all the leg work with getting it installed now.

Comment: i faced same issue. Then i use pods and it's working fine.

Comment: Pods is also not working for me. Have you reference FIRApp in your code? As soon as I do that I get the error.

Comment: yes. i write `[FIRApp configure];` in appDelegate.

Comment: Okay thanks. Thats the line that is causing issues with me. Can you show me what your link libraries with libraries looks like? Maybe I am missing something there?

Comment: sure. [check this image](http://i.imgur.com/2WD3aIT.png). make sure you opened the project using workspace file.

Comment: same issue with this any suggestion or answer for this

Answer (score 31):

First, try `pod update` command on your project root directory. If you see a warning there similar to `target overrides the OTHER_LDFLAGS build setting defined in ...`, check your Target's Build Settings. You'll find a `Other Linker Flag` property there. Set its value as `$(inherited)`.

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had no issue with a Debug configuration. And I had the issue with a Release one. Looks like your solution worked for me. Big thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Im fan of carthage but firebase is only by manual or cocoapods, so I used cocoapods, I  just fixed this by setting `Other Linker Flag` property to `$(inherited)`.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall firebase related pods

```
#pod 'Firebase/Core

#pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
```

Then

```
pod install
```

Reinstall  pods

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
```

then

```
pod install
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked for me just now. The coding equivalent of turning it off and on again...

Answer (score 0):

Try pod update, if does not work then 
.remove the framework from the pod file 
. run "pod update"
.add the frameworks back to the pod file 
.run "pod update"

It worked for me.